# Command with notify-send and rhythmbox-client works, but when I assign a keyboard shortcut for it rhythmbox-client won't start

Tags: shortcut-keys, 18.04, notify-send

I am trying to get the following shortcut to work:

```
notify-send -i rhythmbox "RhythmBox Is Playing" "$(rhythmbox-client --print-playing)"
```

It works fine If I run it from the command line, but when I set it as a keyboard shortcut I just get the text printed out and the program (`rhythmbox-client`) doesn't run.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I got your method working without issue. What version of Ubuntu are you on? run `unname -a` . 

regardless you should try my answer below.

Comment: Strange.  I'm using ubuntu 18.04 (uname -a Linux chud37 4.15.0-20-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 24 06:16:15 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
)

Comment: Have you tried setting another custom shortcut? I would suggest trying something simple just to see if you can get that to work. Then let us know the result.

Comment: @Jeff yes I have other custom shortcuts (all for the rhythmbox-client such as --play-pause) and they work fine.

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to update your question with the information of a working shortcut and an example. And that you have tried the full path without that working.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the full paths

find your paths:

```
$ which rhythmbox
/usr/bin/rhythmbox

$which rhythmbox-client
/usr/bin/rhythmbox-client
```

Then sub the results in instead of just the commands

`notify-send -i /usr/bin/rhythmbox "RhythmBox Is Playing" "$(/usr/bin/rhythmbox-client --print-playing)"`

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Did you try it? Because it's just producing the same results for me :(

Comment: I did try it and it worked, but your method was also working for me. However, I'm on ubuntu 16.04.